# How to make nginx autoindex ignore certain files based on file extensions

Tags: nginx

I enabled autoindex in my nginx conf and now it shows all the files under my root directory.

I want to know if there is a away to write a filter to exclude certain files (eg. files with .png extension).

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Fancy Index module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxFancyIndex) to achieve this. The [fancyindex_ignore](http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxFancyIndex#fancyindex_ignore) directive supports regular expressions which you can leverage to specify file extensions.

Comment: Note that this is a 3rd party module.